# diplomatic riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I am a peacemaker and a diplomat,
a silent watcher to prevent betray.
I’m hiding friends behind my body
and make the rules for you to play.

I can be clear or ambiguous, even graphic.
But when it comes to work, I am snob,
my role is rather .. choreographic
while my buddies do the job.

---

And the question is, who or what is our lazy hero?

Comment: Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the riddle? If there are typos or grammer mistakes, please correct me as I am not a native English speaker. Downvoting "just because" is kind of asocial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> A UI (user interface)

I am a peacemaker and a diplomat,
a silent watcher to prevent betray.

> A UI helps to make peace between the users and the code, and in translating user desires to commands helps to eliminate errors

I’m hiding friends behind my body
and make the rules for you to play.

> The UI sets rules for how you interact with it and hides the actual commands of the OS behind it

I can be clear or ambiguous, even graphic.

> Sometimes it's obvious you're working through a UI and sometimes not, but they can definitely be graphic (GUI - graphical user interface)

But when it comes to work, I am snob,
my role is rather .. choreographic
while my buddies do the job.

> The UI doesn't actually do any of the computing work, it just translates the users commands into commands in the operating language (hence the "choreographing") and the buddies (friends referenced earlier) are the programs/code that actually do the work.

Answer (score 4):

> A contract

---

I am a peacemaker and a diplomat,

> Peacetreaties and trade deals are signed into law

a silent watcher to prevent betray.

> Obviously contracts don't speak, and you can't break them

I’m hiding friends behind my body

> Hiding smallprint in the body of the text

and make the rules for you to play.

> A contract is a codified agreement on what the two parties can do

I can be clear or ambiguous, even graphic.

> Can be plain, vague, or explicit; depending how it's written

But when it comes to work, I am snob,

> Contracts play a huge role in business

my role is rather .. choreographic

> A contract doesn't do anything on its own, it just tells other people what to do

while my buddies do the job

> Could refer to lawyers, or the smallprint referred to as 'friends' earlier in the riddle

Comment: Good reasoning, but this is not the right answer. Can a contract be graphic?

Comment: Sure - Graphic: giving clear and vividly explicit details.

Comment: well, that's a bit of a stretch :) let's say, graphic is important hint in the riddle.

Comment: btw, as I see, you are a software developer.. so, let me give you a hint :) your answer is very good, actually.. just think about it from the software developer perspective.